# col.ToStrings undefined (type Columns has no field or method ToStrings)

Tags: go, methods, types, export, slice

I am attempting to create a type that represents a slice of pointers to another type and define a method for it, my code looks similar to this, albeit a bit simplified for the example:

```
package column

type Column struct {

    name string
}

type Columns []*Column

func (c Column) ToString() string {

    return c.name
}

func (c Columns) ToStrings() []string {

    var strSlice []string

    for _, v := range c {

        strSlice = append(strSlice, v.ToString())
    }

    return strSlice
}
```

It is then called in a separate file like this:

```
import (
    c "main/column"
    "strings"
)

type Columns c.Columns

func ToString(col Columns) string {

    return strings.Join(col.ToStrings(), ",\n")
}
```

However when I try to call the method `ToStrings()` on the exported "Columns" type I get this error:

> columns.ToStrings undefined (type Columns has no field or method
>   ToStrings)

It seems the compiler can't find the method `ToStrings()`. Is there a way around this? Why can't the compiler find the exported method defined for the "Columns" type?

Comment: You created a new `Columns` type with no methods. Why did you create the new type if you want the methods from the original?

Comment: I just thought it was more readable.. so I gather from what you are saying when I make the new type from the old it doesn't carry the methods with it?

Comment: thank you, if you put that as an answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type Columns c.Columns` creates an entirely new type, with a new method set. The only reason to do this is to specifically remove the methods of the exiting type.